Will it be ok to put a layer of sand on top of a clematis container
I have a rather small fungus gnats' infestation with my plants. While I am applying some other solutions, like neem oil, diluted hydrogen peroxide, etc. for my container clematises I would like to try a physical barrier in form of a 1-2cm (half an inch) layer of sand on top of the soil. I already did that with one zamioculcas and it seems to work, but while zamioculcas can be watered once every week or so, clematises require regular watering.
Anyway, while researching clematis container growing resources I have not seen anyone putting a sand layer on top. Mulch - yes, sand no. Sand is also being mixed with soil.
Hence, my question to clematis experts - if I put top layer of sand in my clematis containers will it affect them in any bad way (increased wilt risk, etc.)?

I have no experience with clematis and sand, but I had also an infestation and added sand layers to my pots. It helps, of you can water the pots from the bottom instead the top. If the pot itself has holes in the base, you can add a second pot without holes, places the planted pot inside and add the water in the bigger pot. Or you place a piece of pipe/tube into the soil, to do the water in, which will lead it directly in the bottom part. So the sand and soil will not mix and the top of the pot is not wet and tempting for the flies.
